# Table transpose, \textnumero sign

Tags: pgfplotstable

The MWE

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{textcomp}%%% for \textnumero


\begin{document}

\pgfplotstableread{
N    Ans
1   -36
2    33
3   -52
4   -22
5    33
6    38
7    48
8  -100
}\mytable

\pgfplotstabletranspose[string type,
    colnames from=N,
    input colnames to=N
]\mytablenew{\mytable}

\pgfplotstabletypeset[
    every head row/.style={
        before row=\toprule,
        after row=\midrule
    },
    every last row/.style={
        after row=\bottomrule
    },
string type]{\mytablenew}
\end{document}
```

I want to have `\textnumero` sign instead of N in my final table. Please, any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Insert after `\pgfplotstabletypeset[`

```
columns/N/.style={column name=\textnumero},
```